# where can i specify the compiled migration

Tags: postgresql, typescript, express, sequelize-cli

I'm using postgres database ORM sequelize and I'm using typescript as a backend script for in express nodeJs.

First question: Is there a way to create a model directly to.ts ?

Second question: While trying to migrate the db I'm getting this message:

> "File: 20180424170257-create-todo.ts does not match pattern: /.js$/"

Where can I specify the compiled migration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize doesn't come with it's own type definitions, so in order to add them you need to install them from DefinitelyTyped

```
npm install @types/sequelize
```

You can create a model directly with those type definitions in place. For examples you can check the [tests of sequelize.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/v3/sequelize-tests.ts)

It looks like

```
interface TaskAttributes {
    revision? : number;
    name? : string;
}

// For your instance methods
interface TaskInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<TaskAttributes> {
    upRevision(): void { ... };
}

const GTask = s.define<TaskInstance, TaskAttributes>( 'task', { 
    revision : Sequelize.INTEGER, 
    name : Sequelize.STRING 
} );
```

As for your second question. [Umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug) uses plain JS files for your migrations, so you will have to either compile them to JS files and then use them ( in a build step, before you run the migrations ), or just write them in JavaScript and not TypeScript.

Comment: thank you drinchev ,your solution did guide me to the right places where to solve my problems.